# Is this Mongoose schema correct for saving strings in array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

(SOLUTION IN COMMENTS)

I'm trying to add an array of strings into my DB however each time I try i keep getting the following - i.e. it saves the entire array rather than each item separately:

[image: robomongo]

Also, my mongoose schema looks like this:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [{type: String}],
  createdBy: String
});
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Update - as requested in comments more complete code:

So in backend api:

```
    var newPerson = new Person ({
        tags: req.body.tags, //coming in as ["test", "test2"]
        createdDate: new Date()
    });

newPerson.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Error '});
    } res.json({ success: true, message: 'All OK'});
});
```

And then in my Angular front end:

```
function postService($http, API, auth) {
var self = this;

    self.post = function(tags) {

    return $http.post(API + '/person', {
        tags: JSON.stringify(tags)    //note have tried just tags
         })
    }

}
```

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Is `req.body.tags` a string like `'["test", "test2"]'`, an array containing that string like `['["test", "test2"]']` or an array of strings like `["test", "test2"]`? Based on what you're seeing, it looks like it's not the last one (which is the one you want).

Comment: Its an array of strings when I do a console.log tahts also what I see and furthermore doesnt the screenshot also show that?

Comment: Found the issue - when I do a typeof during the `http.post` the `tag` variable shows as an object, however in the backend its a string.

Comment: And i fixed it using `var recreateArray = req.body.tags.split(',');` in the backend